# How to set up a virtual output?

Tags: software, logic-pro

I'm trying to set up a virtual output so that i can send my output from Logic Pro X (used on Macbook Pro 2018, Catalina) to someone over Team Viewer and they can hear my direct output!

Comment: Hi @unorthodoxkilla. Please provide a little more context on which operating system you have, which versions, etc. (just trying to help you to get more help).

Comment: Hi, I have Macbook Pro 2018, Catalina. I'm using Logic Pro x and Team Viewer :)

Comment: I don't have any experience with Team Viewer, but you might want to look into an internal audio routing program, such as Soundflower?

Comment: Hi Margalo, do you know how to do this on soundflower?

Comment: @unorthodoxkilla there's a way but you won't be able to hear the output but it will routed to team viewer. If that trade-off works for you, reply and i'll post a detailed solution

Comment: SoundFlower is deprecated. You should use BlackHole.
<https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole>